# Can I interrupt form's setting before it show on Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

When I open a Delphi form's pas file, it will show the GUI form designer.  It there any way to get notify via Tools API just before the form show in IDE and let me modify properties of form?  Also is there similar notifier when I execute "View as Form" after "View as Text"?

Comment: Are you sure you want to limit yourself or anyone else by doing this ? Don't you rather want to modify (correct) the properties manually ? If so, then e.g. [`CnPack`](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) has `Property Corrector` which can do these corrections in a scope up to the whole project group in two button clicks. So you would just run this correction wizard before saving the project (group).

Comment: @TLama: I am writing a plugin for Delphi IDE.  The plugin change the PixelsPerInch.  It is too late to update PixelsPerInch before save as PixelsPerInch may have adjust the size of all controls in the form when I switch between Form and Text.

Comment: I see now, you want to protect against changing `PixelsPerInch` manually. I don't know much about Tools API, so just one philosophical question, what if I change it simply in `Object Inspector` ? Don't you want to protect this too ? (+1ed)

Comment: It won't work. You'll need to dev at 96.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It seems like work with 96 PPI is the only solution.  Attempting to maintain 96 in 120 environment is a nightmare.

Comment: Is this related to (http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28922) ?

Comment: @Hendra: Yes it is.  I found some glitch in the plugin I did, hope I can fix it by solving this problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. One question though, if the form's property get changed on loading by ide, then the form state will be changed, isn't it? If the project get opened and saved again (no changes done manualy), the commited form files will confused other developer as if there are changes, but no changes made?

Comment: @Hendra: Yes. you are right.  I think I can't avoid the form modified state problem.  I will most probably ignore this side effect.  Now the problem is when I switch from to text, I inject Scaled to True to make the dfm file stay as is.  When I switch back to form again, the PixelPerInch become 96 and IDE wills scale my form to 120.  This is why I am asking if there is a way to change form's PixelPerInch to 96 before I switch to form.

Comment: But how components supposed to paint at 96 on 120 desktop settings? Another thing is this rescaling operation (back and forth) may introduce rounding off problem. After some iteration, the dimension, and position may be off.

Comment: @Hendra: So what should I do?

Comment: Atm, using the same ppi (96) among all developers looks like the way to go. There are so many things affected, like fonts used(ttf or not), size, position, spacing, etc. Make it works, and having all components looks right in all situations will be tricky.

Comment: @Hendra: I amend the http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28922 to fix more problem found.  I prompt a dialog to user if re-scaled was detected and warn user about switch back to form.